# Stuck in separating chars into strings in my approach. Found a working approach but can not understand it

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to figure out how to break a string to be on character per line.
I.e `ahebhaaa` to be:

```
a  
h  
e  
b  
h  
a  
a  
a
```

I tried:

`$ echo ahebhaaa | sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\1\n\2/g'`
I.e. my intention was "plugin" between chars a new line using capture groups but I get:

```
a  
he  
bh  
aa  
a
```

I guess this has to do with greedy/non-greedy but adding ?* anywhere in this does not do anything.  What am I doing wrong here?

Additionally I found that this:
`echo ahebhaaa | sed 's/[^\n]/&\n/g'`
Does the job. But I don't understand how it works. What is `&`? How does the `[^\n]` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### capture groups

Your first example was close, but you're telling `sed` that you want to take 2 characters at a time with the `\(.\)\(.\)` bit, to do it using a capture group you could adjust it like so:

```
$ echo ahebhaaa | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
a
h
e
b
h
a
a
a
```

#### using &

As to why the `sed` example with the `&` works. The `&` in a search and replace is what ever characters the regular expression matched. So everything that was *not* a `\n`.

#### Examples

```
$ echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/&&/'
123123 abc
```

The first `&` prints the characters that were matched by the pattern (`[0-9]*`), `123`. The second `&` prints them a second time.

```
$ echo "123 abc" | sed 's/ab/&&&/'
123 abababc
```

The pattern we're looking for is `ab`. As we walk the string `123 abc` sed is printing the non-matched characters, `123`. Then the string `ab` is encountered which at that point matches what we're searching and replacing on. So `sed` then replaces it with 3 copies of what matched (`abbab`). Finally `sed` prints the `c`.

The notation `[^\n]` creates a set of *not* a end of line character. So think of `sed` as it's walking along your string of text, `ahebhaaa`, it's testing each of these characters and saying "Is this not a `\n`"?  If it's not a end of line character, then `sed` does a search and replace on this character and the `&` prints what was matched, i.e. the character, along with a new line character. It then repeats this as it walks along the `ahebhaaa` string.

#### References

- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: Great explanation!The `&` is it part of the standard regex?I don't remember using it ever before

Comment: @Jim - yeah it's a standard part, I haven't seen it used myself that much either. I'll add a reference if you want to read up on it a bit more.

Comment: @Jim - see updates.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why the \n comes into play in that example, since it is a single line pattern space situation, so there are no newlines. Therefore this should suffice:

```
sed 's/./&\n/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative in Perl

```
echo "abcdefg"|perl -nle 'print for split//'
```

Comment: +1:Can not figure out how to run perl one-liners from a bash like that

Comment: @Jim `man perlrun` will help you with the usage of switches. "Magic" one-liners like the above make heavy use of Perl's special variables. The above statement, when made explicit, reads `print $_ foreach $_ (split //,$_)` See `man perlvar` for more on special variables.